# Error: Cannot find module '/src' when running 'src/'

Tags: node.js, npm, path, runtime-error, nodemon

I try to start the `src/` folder with node (`node src/`) or nodemon (`npm start`) to start the three `.js` files in that path and strangely it does not find the `src/` folder

**I clarify that the files start perfectly when started separately**

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon src/"
}
```

I find it very strange since I start all my projects in the same way and I have never had this problem before.

```js
teyrox@teyrox:~/project$ npm start
...
[nodemon] starting `node src/`
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/project/src'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting..
```

```js
teyrox@teyrox:~/project$ node src/
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/project/src'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

And yes, I run these commands from the `/` path of the project

[image: File tree]

EDIT: My `main` property in `package.json` is `src/`, I tried changing it to `src/server.js` but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the name of the `server.js` file to `index.js` and it works normally.

Apparently, when starting a directory node looks for `index.js` by default.

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace scripts inside package.json

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon src/server.js"
  }
```

Comment: I don't want to start only `server.js`, I want to start `server.js`, `database.js` and `xt.js` simultaneously (by simply running `src/` as I do with all my projects, but here this error started to occur in a strange way

Comment: import database.js and xr.js file in server.js